# How to display logo in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am just learning Drupal and I am having trouble to display a logo on my custom theme..

page.tpl.php:

```
<a href="<?php print $front_page;?>">
<img src="/<?php print $directory;?>/img/logo.png" alt="<?php print $site_name;?>" height="80"
width="150" />
</a>
```

As I look inspecter, I see that the path is correct:

```
<img src="/themes/bony/img/logo.png" alt="Haldun Atar Drupal Page" height="80" width="150">
```

On Appearance > Settings panel I also entered the path: themes/bony/img/logo.png

I just can't display the logo.. Where do I search the problem?

P.s: I have the logo img in img file.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can just upload it on the theme settings page.

Comment: I did that also, but no change..

Comment: I added an answer on how to print it out if you uploaded on the theme settings page.

Answer (score 1):

If you uploaded the file on the theme settings page, you should have a $logo variable in the page.tpl.php (though this will depend on if you have overridden the preprocess).
You can see how it is output if you look in the 'modules/system/page.tpl.php'.
In the system page.tpl.php it is output like this:

```
  <?php if ($logo): ?>
    <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo">
      <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
    </a>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the src link in inspector does it take you to the image? If not try an absolute path like `/<absolute>/<path>/<to>/<your>/<folder>`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear cache after you made the changes?

Admin -> configuration -> performance -> clear cache